# php date() function doesn't give me the year right

Tags: php, date

```
echo date("Y", strtotime('2019-W01'));
```

This should give me '2019' right?

Nope, it gives '2018'.

When it is

```
echo date("Y", strtotime('2019-W02'));
```

This time it gives '2019', right.

I suppose this is a bug or is there something I don't know?

(default timezone is UTC when testing this)

Comment: Are you sure your format is valid ? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: Week 1 2019 started 31st december 2018

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, I have been using it frequently, the 'W' format also exists in the document you sent.

Comment: @ivion So, the function gives result according to starting day of the week?

Comment: Yes, it is a Definition See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is working as expected. `echo $date->format('Y');` returns 2018 because the **first** week of **2019** is the day **2018-12-31**. Let's see when I try with format `Y-m-d` e.g `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2019-W01'));` it returns `2018-12-31` and for `echo date("Y", strtotime('2019-W01'));` it is returning `2019` because it is `2019-01-07`. Let's try this `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2019-W02'));`

```
<?php
$date= new \DateTime('2019-W01');
echo $date->format('Y');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
//echo date("Y", strtotime('2019-W01'));
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/GsF1t

Comment: Ok, it is taking the first day of the week into account. I supposed it would take the year into consideration.

Comment: Yet another example of why working with dates programmatically is so much fun